# Android Relative Layout not displaying elements as it should

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout, android

I'm learning Android, and trying to make a relatively simple app, which downloads an XML and displays some result based on an input parameter. 
I'm using Android Studio 0.4.6 and the drag-and-drop UI designer. 
My problem is, that my UI does not look the same as in the designer when I launch the app in the emulator.

This is how it looks in the designer:

[image]

And this is how it actually looks in the emulator:

[image: http://imgur.com/BDwKaQk]

Here's the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#95ffa1"
    android:id="@+id/mainActLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/minTemp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/maxTemp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/humidity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/pressure"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="false">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSearchActivity"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save To History"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View History"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear History"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText5"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/wind"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clouds"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:editable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you help me out, please?

Comment: The layout is correct, it's the way you think it's supposed to work that's not. You're not taking into account the different variations of screen sizes, and just expecting it to show up the same across different devices. If you want it to look the same across all devices, you should be using different variations of sizes and margins depending on the current device's size/density.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#95ffa1"
    android:id="@+id/mainActLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/minTemp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/maxTemp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/humidity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/pressure"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="false">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSearchActivity"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save To History"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View History"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear History"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText5"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/wind"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clouds"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:editable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see different problems.

First, in the bottom you have some elements over elements. You try to resolve with ScrollView container.(Put all your code inside Scrollview)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</ScrollView>
```

Second, i see the proportion size of textview, edittext and button are diferentes. I recommend read about the weightSum, this is the way you will have the button and all elements look same in differences screen size.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum)